# Does every distribution with a Lebesgue integrable density also admit a Riemann integrable density?

Tags: probability, integration, density-function

Suppose we have a continuous distribution function $F$ with density $f$ such that $f$ is Lebesgue integrable. Does $F$ then also have a density that is Riemann integrable?
Here's an attempt to construct a counterexample. Take the density
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } x \in [0,1]\setminus\mathbb{Q},\\
0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
The Lebesgue integral of this function is $1,$ yet it isn't Riemann integrable. However, one could just use 
$$
\tilde{f}(x)=
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } x \in [0,1],\\
0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
instead which has the same cumulative distribution function, but is also Riemann integrable.
So my question is, can such a modification always be carried out?

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you need as a counter-example.  The Cantor function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function

Comment: One way is to consider an everywhere unbounded function on $[0,1]$, which you can construct like $f(x) =\sum_n a_n(x-q_n) ^{1/2}$, where the $q_n$ is an enumeration of the rationals in $[0,1]$ and $a_n$ an appropriate sequence of positive numbers.

Comment: @herbsteinberg That's a distribution which doesn't have any density at all - Lebesgue or Riemann integrable. But I'm already assuming that I have existence and Lebesgue integrability.

Comment: The probability distribution for which your example is a density is the same as that for which the indicator of the unit interval is a density, i.e. it is the uniform distribution.

Comment: @herbsteinberg : The Cantor distribution is not an example of the kind requested here, since it doesn't have a density at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a set $C$ like the standard Cantor set, but of measure $>0$. Take the characteristic function of it.    Note that $C$ closed and the interior of $C$ is empty. Moreover, $C$ is such that for every open interval $I$ that intersects $C$ we have $\mu(C\cap I)>0$. Therefore, for every $x \in C$ and $I$ open interval around $x$ we have $\mu(C\cap I)>0$ and $\mu((\mathbb{R}\setminus C)\cap I)>0$.

Consider  a function $f$ that is equal almost everywhere to $\chi_C$. We conclude from the above that for every $x\in C$ and every $I$ open interval around $x$, $f$ takes both values $0$ and $1$ in $I$. Therefore $f$ cannot be continuous at $x$. So the set of discontinuities of $f$ contains $C$, and so is of measure $>0$. Therefore, $f$ is not Riemann integrable.

Conclusion: there does not exist a Riemann integrable function $f$ such that 
$$\int_0^x f(t) dt =\int_0^x \chi_C(x) dx $$ for all $x$.

Added: This should not be confused with the Cantor distribution, which is a continuous, but singular distribution.

The Cantor distribution is like this : take the standard Cantor set $C$ (of measure $0$) There exists a Borel measure $\nu$ on $C$ that has total mass $1$. ( since $C$ is like $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$) . Define the distribution on $\mathbb{R}$ by $m([0,x])=\nu(C\cap [0,x])$. This gives a continuous, but singular distribution on $\mathbb{R}$, supported on the set $C$, of measure $0$.

Comment: Note that the following look different from each other: $$ \begin{align} & \mathbb C \setminus C \\ \\ & \mathbb C \backslash C \end{align} $$ The former uses \setminus and the latter uses \backslash. The latter doesn't have the spacing appropriate to a binary operation symbol.

Comment: What is "a distribution of function type"? $\qquad$

Comment: Just showing $f$ is not Riemann-integrable is not enough. The function given in the question is also not Riemann-integrable, but the probability distribution for which it is a density does have a Riemann-integrable density, which is almost everywhere equal to the given function. You need to show that $f$ is not almost everywhere equal to any Riemann-integrable function.

Comment: @Michael Hardy; what is shown is that any function that is equal to $\chi_C$ almost everywhere will be discontinuous at every point of $C$.  So there is no Riemann integrable function that is equal to $\chi_C$ almost everywhere. Hope that makes it clearer.

Comment: Could you add something explicit about that to the answer?

Comment: @Michael Hardy: Reedited the answer, hope it got clearer. Thanks for the input. Cheers!

Comment: Doesn't this give a Cantor distribution https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_distribution which, contrary to my assumption, doesn't have any density at all?

Comment: @SebastianOberhoff : No, it doesn't, because it's a "fat Cantor set", i.e. it says "like the standard Cantor set but with measure $>0.$" The word "like" presumably means topologically like it. For example, instead of deleting middle thirds, delete middle fourths. Then the measure of what you've deleted is $\frac 1 4 + \frac 1 8 + \frac 1 {16} + \cdots = \frac 1 2.$ The measure of the resulting Cantor set is then $1 - \frac 1 2 = \frac 1 2. \qquad$

Comment: @Sebastian Oberhoff: No, and I added an explanation in the answer. Note that in the answer the distribution  the cnaracteristic function of $C$.as a density. If we did this with the standard $C$ of measure $0$ we would get the $0$ distribution.  In the Cantor case, one starts with a probability measure on $C$ (not the restriction of Lebesgue measure)  and pushes it to a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Michael Hardy: yes, that's a very good point you made about $C$.